# enforcing objects through std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a design problem. In my application, I have a few classes to be managed with `std::shared_ptr`. We want to enforce that these classes should be created by our `std::shared_ptr` only. Therefore, we thought to do something like:

```
template <typename T>
class make_sharable_only
{
    make_sharable_only();
    ~make_sharable_only();

public:
    template <typename ...Args>
    static std::shared_ptr<T> CreateShareInstance(Args ...args)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<T> ptr;
        ptr.reset(new T(args...));

        return ptr;
    }

};
    class A: public make_sharable_only<A>
    {

    };

void f()
{
    auto aPtr = A::CreateShareInstance();
}
```

But, the problem is that even `CreateShareInstance` is not able to create the instance of A. I dont want to create the `friend` relationship. Is there a way to define such a base class for this purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Help! I have <problem> but I don't want to use <language feature specifically designed to solve <problem>>. Well then...

Answer (score 3):

> I dont want to create the `friend` relationship.

Why not? Why reject a working solution?

If you want some other class to have special access to private/protected members then either it needs to derive from your class (not be a base of your class) or it needs to be a friend of your class.

I assume you meant to have a private constructor in `A`.

Also this:

```
    std::shared_ptr<T> ptr;
    ptr.reset(new T(args...));

    return ptr;
```

should be:

```
    return make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

Once you write it like that it's so simple that there's no reason to try and use a base class, just put a factory function on `A`, it only takes three lines of code (four to make it a template):

```
class A {
  A() = default;
public:
  static std::shared_ptr<A> create() {
    return std::make_shared<A>();
  }
};
```

Comment: `make_shared<A>(new A());` - shouldn't that be `make_shared<A>()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate `shared_ptr<make_sharable_only>` because `make_sharable_only::~make_sharable_only` is private. You can leave the constructor private and make the destructor public (ok, someone could delete a raw pointer obtained from shared_ptr, but doing that by accidentaly is unlikely).